# SQL Server: How to limit stored procedure to only show one (next) matching record

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I am using the following stored procedure to fetch some data from a database. 
The column meetingDate is formatted as datetime and only contains valid data.

How do I have to amend the stored procedure so that it only shows me the next matching record and not all of them ?

**Example:**

Today = 18/02/2014; 
the database contains records with meetingDate = 20/02/2014, 27/02/2014 and 04/03/2014; 
in that case the result should only be the record for 20/02/2014 as the next matching one in the future.

**My stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchMeetings]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      A.meetingID,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), A.meetingDate, 106) AS meetingDate,
                A.created,
                A.createdBy,
                A.updated,
                A.updatedBy,
                B.speaker AS speaker,
                B.topic AS topic
    FROM        MeetingDates A
    INNER JOIN  MeetingDetails B
    ON          A.meetingID = B.meetingID
    WHERE       meetingDate >= GETDATE()
    ORDER BY    meetingDate, speaker, topic
    FOR XML PATH('meeting'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: may be date column format is different.what is data-type of date column and date parameter data-type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SELECT TOP 1

```
SELECT      A.meetingID,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), A.meetingDate, 106) AS meetingDate,
            A.createdBy,
            B.speaker AS speaker,
            B.topic AS topic
            FROM MeetingDates A
INNER JOIN  MeetingDetails B
ON          A.meetingID = B.meetingID
            WHERE a.meetingDate IN (
SELECT      TOP 1(a.meetingDate)
FROM        MeetingDates A
WHERE       meetingDate >= GETDATE()
ORDER BY    meetingDate ASC)
ORDER BY    speaker, topic
FOR XML PATH('meeting'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Comment: I just saw this is messing up the JOIN and then only returns the first record from there as well but here I need all matching records.

Comment: What do you mean by it's messing up the join? What exactly is the query supposed to show? Is it one meeting with many meeting details? And what is it actually showing?

Comment: Thanks for the quick help (sorry, this got deleted by accident in my previous comment). For all the A. items the Top 1 is perfect as I only need the next meeting but one meeting can have multiple topics on the B. table so there I would need all matching items.

Comment: See amendment to my answer which seems to give you what you want. I've tried it with a basic test database.

Answer (score 1):

Use windowed function. it's compatible sql server 2005+

here is an example with my data

```
with p as (
 select *, dense_RANK() over (order by foryear desc, formonth desc) as rnk 
from RISK_TRANS.dbo.mytable
) 

select * from p
where rnk = 2
```

My keys are 2014 - 1 for last and 2013-12; 2013-11. It only picks me 2013-12 as you would expect

can you try this : (i'm not sure syntax is correct, i only did the changes, not runned)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchMeetings]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    with p as (
    SELECT A.meetingID,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), A.meetingDate, 106) AS meetingDate,
                A.created,
                A.createdBy,
                A.updated,
                A.updatedBy,
                B.speaker AS speaker,
                B.topic AS topic,
                DENSE_RANK() over (order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), A.meetingDate, 106) desc) rnk
    FROM        MeetingDates A
    INNER JOIN  MeetingDetails B
    ON          A.meetingID = B.meetingID
    WHERE       meetingDate >= GETDATE())

    select meetingid, meetingdate, createddate, createdby, updated, updatedby, speaker, topic 
    from p
    ORDER BY    meetingDate, speaker, topic
    FOR XML PATH('meeting'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! - I am getting an error for the DENSE_RANK line: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FetchMeetings, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

Comment: yes sorry forgot the bracket after dense_rank :) like i said i'm not 100% confident with syntaxt

Comment: Thanks a lot - this seems to work as well. I am doing some more testing on this now.

Answer (score 0):

try using SELECT 1 construction, check here [1](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/02/21/sql-server-shortcut-to-select-only-1-row-from-table/)